# Python - read lat/long coordinates from text-file containing separation sign

Tags: python, numpy

Originally, the text file were for the use of GMT (The Generic Mapping Tools).
The format is similar as following:

```
122   55
122   56
122.5 57
>
123   25.25
123   25.27
```

where '>' is recognized as a separation sign for different segments of lines.

Now, I'm using `Basemap` from `mpl_toolkits` to plot lines on a map. All I need is a 2D numpy array to pass coordinates into a function more or less the same as `plt.plot` or `plt.scatter`.

Here's a simple solution which I came up with:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from io import StringIO

file = open("latlon.txt", "r")
data = file.read()

data = data.replace('>','nan\tnan') 
# Use nan,nan to isolate different segments of lines in plt.plot
# Also, np.genfromtxt cannot directly read such kinds of data
#  due to inconsistent of columns for certain lines in the file,
#  hence the replacement
line_xy = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(unicode(data)))

(plotting stuffs...)
```

I found this way kind of tricky and not really like it... Is there any solution which is more commonly, explicitly or formally used for such case? Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) toolkit, then the pandas.read_csv() function can be used to parse your data, and turn it into an array of floats:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
array = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',)).values
```

Here, the `read_csv()` will treat the columns in your datafile as separated by whitespace, and return a DataFrame of strings. The `apply()` line then converts those into floating-point numbers, coercing invalid entries (like your '>') into NaNs. The `.values` attribute then extracts the contents of the DataFrame as an ordinary `numpy.ndarray`. This gives:

```
array([[ 122.  ,   55.  ],
       [ 122.  ,   56.  ],
       [ 122.5 ,   57.  ],
       [    nan,     nan],
       [ 123.  ,   25.25],
       [ 123.  ,   25.27]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is precisely what I need ! I'll dig into Pandas and see what else I can get there, had never used the toolkit before.